# Why does gmusicbrowser not integrate well with the sound menu?

Tags: indicator-sound

I'm having a little issue with gmusicbrowser's integration with the Ubuntu 11.10 sound menu. After I installed the player, it appeared in the menu like it should, but it only opens one time per session. If I close it, it won't open anymore using the Ubuntu sound menu - only if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> or a terminal. It just opens again using the menu after I logout or doing `compiz --replace`. The other players I have in the menu open with no problem.

Gmusicbrowser also don't have the Play/pause/next/previous controllers. The other players do.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is based on Ubuntu 12.04, but should work as well with 11.10.

Gmusicbrowser (1.1.9) contains mpris2 (do not use mpris1, since the soundmenu requires mpris2), notifications, and gnome multimedia keys integration as a plugins:

[image]

When those plugins are activated, full soundmenu/notification/gnome integration is there:

[image]

This works perfectly (inlcuding starting gmusicbrowser via the sound menu, as often as you want per session).

If this does **not** work for you in your setup, then you should report it as a bug. The developer of gmusicbrowser (Quentin Sculo) is very active in fixing bugs: The gmusicbrowser site states:

> Feel free to mail me (in english or french) any
>   comments/suggestions/bugs (please include "gmusicbrowser" or "gmb" in
>   the subject), post them in the forums, or ask them in irc
>   (#gmusicbrowser on freenode.net, be patient for anwsers).